# function gives me the error unorderable types: str() > int()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

**count_pos** is supposed to input a list of numbers and return the quantity of positive values in that list.

```
def count_pos():
    numbers=list(input("Please enter a list of numbers separated by commas: "))
    count=0
    for number in numbers:
        if number > 0:
           count += 1
           add=sum(1 for number in numbers if number > 0)
           return add
```

When I input

> -1, 2, -5, 0, 3

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 11, in <module>
    print (count_pos())
  File "so.py", line 6, in count_pos
    if number > 0:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Comment: Number is a string (actually a character) and you're trying to compare it to an integer.  You probably want to `numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers.split(',')]` or something along those lines.

Comment: what @mgilson said, but to clarify, the previous line defining `numbers` needs to be without the `list()`

Comment: One editing note: your original text says that **count_pos** "takes a list of numbers".  This usually means that the calling program is responsible to supply that list, and your function *must* have an input parameter, rather than reading user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem as given**

The code you posted actually works in Python 2.7; it's Python 3 that doesn't have this **list(input())** functionality.

Fortunately, your variable names are very clear.  Others have detailed the immediate problem -- and I up-voted the explanation I think is particularly good.  Let's fix this without damaging your program design:

```
def count_pos():
user_input = input("Please enter a list of numbers seperated by commas"))
# user_input is a raw string of the input, such as "1, 2, 3, 4"
# break this into individual numbers:
str_numbers = user_input.split(',')

# str_numbers would now be ["1", " 2", " 3", " 4"]
# These individual strings are suitable to convert to integer
numbers = [int(str_num) for str_num in str_numbers]

# NOW we can continue with the rest of your program, as written:
count=0
for number in numbers:
    if number > 0:
       count += 1
       add=sum(1 for number in numbers if number > 0)
       return add
```

---

**Additional Clean-up**

First of all, you return after you find the first positive number in your loop; **count** never gets higher than 1.  However, you'll get the right answer, since your **add=** statement actually replaces what the loop would do.  You can get rid of the loop entirely, and just use

```
return sum(1 for number in numbers if number > 0)
```

If you need to do this in a loop, then let it run to the end so it can do its job.  Only then do you return the result:

```
for number in numbers:
    if number > 0:
       count += 1

return count
```

---

**Editing note**

Your original text says that count_pos "takes a list of numbers". This usually means that the calling program is responsible to supply that list, and your function must have an input parameter, rather than reading user input.  In that case, your entire problem is solved by correcting the function header and removing the input and conversion, and using only your one-line solution:

```
def count_pos(numbers):
    return sum(1 for number in numbers if number > 0)
```

Comment: Upvoted for reading the OP's code a lot more thoroughly than I did and giving a very full explanation of what the asker wanted, rather than what he asked. :)

Comment: Ha!  And I happen to be the one who up-voted yours, for walking OP through the Python logic so nicely.  :-)

Comment: I saw! But you still caught a bunch more than I did, since I stopped at solving his immediate problem, as you said. ^_^ You actually solved the whole issue for him.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Your help was much appreciated :DDDD

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a single string.

`list(input(...))` returns a list with a single string in it.

`for number in numbers:` assigns `number` to that string, so it's now a string.

`if number > 0` is then checking if the string in `number` is larger than `0`.

And a string and an integer cannot be compared.

Presumably, what you want to do is change this line:

```
numbers=list(input("Please enter a list of numbers seperated by commas"))
```

To this:

```
numbers=map(float, list(input("Please enter a list of numbers seperated by commas").split(',')))
```

That will turn the string from `input` into a list of strings (it'll split up comma-separated values), and then `map(float, ...)` will apply the `float()` function to each element of that list to turn that list into a list of floats.

Answer (score 1):

because input will give you a string and string will be converted into collection of  single string literals so if you enter

```
1 2 3
```

your list will be collection of strings , where space cannot be converted to int or compared

```
[' ', '1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3']
```

and within your `if` statement this is giving you the error at first comparison `if ' ' > 0`

so use this to convert your input into an integer list

```
numbers=list(map(int,input("Please enter a list of numbers seperated by commas").strip().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this specific error is actually that you do `number > 0`. The left side is a string (as I'll explain) and the right side is an integer. And Python doesn't allow you to compare strings and integers like that.

The `list` call doesn't work as you'd expect. `input()` returns a string, and if you do `list("A_STRING")` you'll get a list with each character (`["A", "_"…]`).

You probably want to look for [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), which separates a string with a given separator and returns you a list of strings. And then you actually need to convert each string in the list to a number (for example by using `int(THE_STRING)` or `float(THE_STRING)`).

So something like this:

```
text = input(…)
elements = text.split(",")
numbers = [int(element) for element in elements]
```